# Making my function better

Tags: javascript, php, html, performance

How could I make this code more efficient? Net-beans is saying that I have too many lines in my functions.   Also it is saying that where I have my if statement I should introduce a new function.  Could some body help me with creating a good function and making my function smaller

```
function dispalyEvent($weekNr, $week, $year){
    echo "<p>";
    $gendate = new DateTime();
    $gendate->setISODate($year,$week,$weekNr);

    $month = $gendate->format('m');
    $day =  $gendate->format('d');
    $event_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calendar ORDER BY starttime"); 

    while($event = mysql_fetch_array($event_query)) { 
    $startYear = $event['startyear'];
    $startMonth = $event['startmonth'];
    $startDay = $event['startdate'];
    $endYear = $event['endyear'];
    $endMonth = $event['endmonth'];
    $endDay = $event['enddate'];

    $period = new DatePeriod(
            new DateTime($startYear.$startMonth.$startDay),
            new DateInterval('P1D'),
            new DateTime($endYear.$endMonth.$endDay +1)
    );

    $currentDate = $year."-".$month."-".$day;

        foreach ($period as $savedDate) {   

            if ($currentDate == $savedDate->format('Y-m-d')){
                buildEvent($event['ad'], $event['starttime'], $event['title'], $event['endtime'], $event['location'], $event['address'], $event['price'], $event['description']);
            }    
            if ($event['Approved'] == "Approved"){
                    buildEvent($event['ad'], $event['starttime'], $event['title'], $event['endtime'], $event['location'], $event['address'], $event['price'], $event['description']);
            }

        }

    }
    echo "</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: One way of improving it is to stop using the `mysql` extension, since it's officially deprecated. You should instead use either [`MySQLi`](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/PDO).

Comment: If you want someone to review your code you should post on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 2):

Aside from switching to [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/PDO) for safety and support reasons; you can also clear most of your unused code.

For example: you don't actually have to create new variables for every array-value.

Here's what I would make of it:

```
<?php
function dispalyEvent($weekNr, $week, $year){
    echo "<p>";
    $currentDate = new DateTime()->setISODate($year,$week,$weekNr)->format('Y-m-d');

    $event_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calendar ORDER BY starttime");         
    while($event = mysql_fetch_array($event_query)) { 
        $period = new DatePeriod(
            new DateTime($event['startyear'].$event['startmonth'].$event['startday']),
            new DateInterval('P1D'),
            new DateTime($event['endyear'].$event['endmonth'].(event['$endday']+1))
        );

        foreach ($period as $savedDate) {   
            if ($currentDate == $savedDate->format('Y-m-d') || $event['Approved'] == "Approved"){
                buildEvent($event['ad'], $event['starttime'], $event['title'], $event['endtime'], $event['location'], $event['address'], $event['price'], $event['description']);
            }
        }
    }
    echo "</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I get an error on  $currentDate = new DateTime()->setISODate($year,$week,$weekNr)->format('Y-m-d');

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't take NetBeans warning that seriously, not that kind at least. Most of them are configurable and you can change them. 
Those are useful when working with a team, if you want to "force" your team to follow certain rules you set those rules to help you verify the code.

Other than what Tularis said I don't see what you can do. Please remember that a good code is not always short, code that is easily understandable is as good as it gets.